# CSS conflicts in react

Tags: css, reactjs, dom

How to use normal CSS without using any modules or external dependencies like CSS module or styled-components in React avoiding class name collision or CSS overriding to other components?

Comment: You can't. Two ways only scoped css and global css. css modules or styled components are for scoped css. And another one is classical way and it is global scoped.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways:

- to scope it under a class name, for a certain component:

  `.employee-data .warning { ... }`
- to scope it under a certain page

  `#about-us-page .photo { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the problem is classes are already declared and the file is a little bit large and each section has a number of classes. So if I want to apply the CSS module then have to write all the class Names again in this large file. Actually, I wanted a solution based on normal CSS which is already developed. I also using the Scoped.css package but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your style.css

```
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #1a202c;
  padding: 8px;
  min-width: 64px;
 
  background: transparent;
 
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}
 
.button:hover {
  background: #1a202c;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Your App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
 
function App() {
  ...
}
 
function Basket({ items, onClick }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.name}
          <button
            type="button"
            className="button"
            onClick={() => onClick(item)}
          >
            {item.isFavorite ? 'Unlike' : 'Like'}
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CRA app, I would recommend CSS Modules Stylesheet as there are inbuilt with CRA and easy to use.

there is no challenge just update the filename as xyz.module.css and import

```
import styles from './xyz.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles

<button className={styles.error}>Error Button</button>
```

Here **error** is your class name same as regular CSS.

Now u may have same classname as **error** in another css file like abc.module.css then simply

```
import styles from './xyz.module.css';
import stylesA from './abc.module.css'; 
<button className={styles.error}>Error Button</button>
<button className={stylesA.error}>Error Button</button>

~~~ xyz.module.css ~~~
.error {
  background-color: red;
}

~~~ abc.module.css ~~~
.error {
  background-color: green;
}
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the problem is classes are already declared and the file is a little bit large and each section has a number of classes. So if I want to apply the CSS module then have to write all the class Names again in this large file. Actually, I wanted a solution based on normal CSS which is already developed. I also using the Scoped.css package but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking is called [CSS Modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

An example would be

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Button.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles
import './another-stylesheet.css'; // Import regular stylesheet

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    // reference as a js object
    return <button className={styles.error}>Error Button</button>;
  }
}
```

The output will be like this. See the hash at the end of classname

```
<button class="Button_error_ax7yz">Error Button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the problem is classes are already declared and the file is a little bit large and each section has a number of classes. So if I want to apply the CSS module then have to write all the class Names again in this large file. Actually, I wanted a solution based on normal CSS which is already developed. I also using the Scoped.css package but it's not working.

Comment: @MIRTAUHIDULISLAM You dont have to rewrite. Import your style sheet like this - `import classes from ‘./Header.css’;` and apply them like `<div className={classes.Header}>...</div>`  Check [this](https://0n3z3r0n3.medium.com/scoping-css-classes-to-a-component-in-reactjs-using-css-modules-c294dc6a0e02)